# Replace expression in mongoDB query by an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a mongoDB query

```
test.find({$or : [ {"timeIn":"2018-1-31 11:57"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 11:58"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 11:59"} ]  }, {"email": 1, "_id": 0}).toArray(function (err,data){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

How I can replace expression `{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 11:57"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 11:58"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 11:59"}` by an array. Like this

```
test.find({$or : [ array ]  }, {"email": 1, "_id": 0}).toArray(function (err,data){
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `$in`, it takes an array of values to be matched

```
test.find({timeIn : {$in: ["2018-1-31 11:57","2018-1-31 11:58","2018-1-31 11:59"]}  }, {"email": 1, "_id": 0}).toArray(function (err,data){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alex, do you want something like this:

```html
var arrQuery = [];

var query1 = {'name':'AC3 Series Charger'};
var query2 =  {'price':200};
var query3 =  {'type':'tv'};
arrQuery.push(query1);
arrQuery.push(query2);
arrQuery.push(query3);

db.products.find({$or:arrQuery})
```

Just adjust it for your needs.

Comment: Thanks you for your support.